# Eclipse CDT: Is it possible to define a tool in an Eclipse IDE that has no output?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

We're using Eclipse as an IDE for our own development tools, and I'm trying to add support for an new tool that will process an executable file, but leave it with the same name (i.e. the tool won't have any obvious outputs). So, for example, if my tool is called "MY_TOOL", then I'm trying to generate a makefile like this:

```
all: a.exe

a.exe: $(SRC_OBJS)
    gcc <BLAH BLAH>
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'

MY_TARGET: a.exe
    MY_TOOL a.exe
```

But I'm stuck. I tried omitting "outputType" from the tool definition, but that means I don't define a target in the makefile; if I *do* include a (fake) outputType, then the (fake) output file ends up on the command line.

So, is there  a way to define a tool with no output and still have a valid makefile?